# Using the Twitter API on a local computer instead of the web?

Tags: twitter, web-scraping, twitter-oauth, tweepy

To access Twitter in Python you need to register a Twitter App. This gets you the following information that you need to authenticate with Twitter:

```
> consumer_key = '***' 
> consumer_secret = '***' 
> access_token = '***'
> access_token_secret = '***'
```

However, to register for a Twitter app, you are required to provide the URL from which the app will access Twitter. All I want to do is scrape tweets matching a certain search phrase. How do I do this without having a web accessible server? Should I use a web scraping site like morph.io?

Answer (score 0):

You can enter any information on that field and your key/secret/tokens will still work from a local computer.